# How to run progress bar in background?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am try to create progress bar in background by using asynkTask.I am downlroading file from server and show the progress of file downloading by using progress bar this is working fine.

For creating this progressbar i am refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/).

My code :

```
 package com.example.androidhive;

   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Environment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;

 public class AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

// button to show progress dialog
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyAudio";
ProgressBar progressBar;
// File url to download
private static String file_url = "my url";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);


    File f = new File(file);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    } else {
        // f.delete();
    }
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            if (progressBar.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            // OutputStream output = new
            // FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Audio/downloadedfile.jpg");
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file+
                    "audio.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        // pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        // dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        if (progressBar.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        // setting downloaded into image view
        // my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

}
    }
```

But my problem was when i am close my application and reopen my progress bar is not showing.
But my file download in background.I want to show the progress of downloading file if app will close and re-open it again i want to show progress of download.

How to i create this any one please help me...

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, all your ui updates such as the progress bar you're displaying, "dies" when you leave your app. You can see the activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more information.

You can try using a sync adapter approach (although it's a bit harder to implement).

Take a read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Progress). In that example from the developer docs, you can adapt it for your needs, that means, creating a notification to show the progress of the download, and not relying if the user leaves your app or not.